# No bluetooth and unstable wireless connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 for some time. My machine is equipped with a wireless card which also supports Bluetooth. Everything was working fine and after some updates, Bluetooth adapter was gone. Then, I switched to 16.04 recently. Still, I don't have Bluetooth and a very unstable wireless connection which is dropped sometimes, and also wireless adapter is lost. I tried certain stuff which I found, but none of those worked. Help to resolve this is very much appreciated.

Command outputs:

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
---
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi + BT4.0 combo HMC
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

~$ lsusb
---
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 064e:9302 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

~$ rfkill list
---
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
---
<nothing>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, I Added the asked **command outputs**. Can somebody please suggest me a solution?

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list` and `dmesg | grep -i blue`.